# What's wrong with this code? I'm new in C

Tags: c, struct

The compiler gives an error about uninitialized i, j and k, although I used them before, please tell me what’s wrong, I’m just starting to learn C and I’m stuck here.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h> 
struct Book { 
    char title[100]; 
    int volume; 
    int year; 
    char author[100]; 
}; 
struct Magazine { 
    char title[100]; 
    int volume; 
    int month; 
    int year; 
    char editorialBoard[100]; 
}; 
struct Newspaper { 
    char title[100]; 
    int volume; 
    int day; 
    int month; 
    int year; 
    char editor[100]; 
}; 
struct Book books[10]; 
struct Magazine magazines[10]; 
struct Newspaper newspapers[10];  
int main(){ 
    int numBooks,numMagazine,numNewspapers,year; 
    printf("Enter the number of books: "); 
    scanf("%d",&numBooks); 
    printf("Enter number of journals: "); 
    scanf("%d",&numMagazine); 
    printf("Enter number of newspapers: "); 
    scanf("%d",&numNewspapers); 
    for(int i=0;i<numBooks;i++){  
        printf("Book %d\n",i+1); 
        printf("Title: "); 
        scanf("%s",&books[i].title); 
        printf("Volume: "); 
        scanf("%d",&books[i].volume); 
        printf("Year: "); 
        scanf("%d",&books[i].year); 
        printf("Author: "); 
        gets(books[i].author); 
    } 
    for(int j=0;j<numMagazine;j++){ 
        printf("Journal %d\n",j+1); 
        printf("Title: "); 
        scanf("%s",&magazines[j].title); 
        printf("Volume: "); 
        scanf("%d",&magazines[j].volume); 
        printf("Month: "); 
        printf("Year: "); 
        scanf("%d",&magazines[j].year); 
        scanf("%d",&magazines[j].month); 
        printf("Editors: "); 
        gets(magazines[j].editorialBoard); 
    } 
    for(int k=0;k<numNewspapers;k++){ 
        printf("Newspaper %d\n",k+1); 
        printf("Title: "); 
        scanf("%s",&newspapers[k].title); 
        printf("Volume: "); 
        scanf("%d",&newspapers[k].volume); 
        printf("Month: "); 
        printf("Year: "); 
        printf("Day: "); 
        scanf("%d",&newspapers[k].year); 
        scanf("%d",&newspapers[k].month); 
        scanf("%d",&newspapers[k].day); 
        printf("Editors: "); 
        gets(newspapers[k].editor); 
    }    
    printf("\nEnter the year: "); 
    scanf("%d",&year); 
    int n; 
    for(n=0;n<numBooks;++n){ 
        if(books[i].year == year) 
            printf("Book: %s, Author: %s\n",books[i].title,books[i].author); 
    }  
    int l; 
    for(l=0;l<numMagazine;++l){ 
        if(magazines[j].year == year) 
            printf("Magazine: %s, Editors: %s\n",magazines[j].title,books[j].editorialBoard); 
    }      
    for(int m = 0; m<numNewspapers ; m++){ 
        if(newspapers[k].year == year){ 
            printf("Newpaper: %s , Editor: %s \n",newspapers[k].title ,newspapers[k].editor); 
        }   
    }       
    return 0;  
}
```

I tried to change elements but it doesn't work

Comment: First thing that is wrong: you have a blank line between each and every line. Why?

Comment: @Jabberwocky I assume because OP didn't format it as code initially and needed to place newlines so SO doesn't merge all in one line. I've edited the post to format code but not going to remove redundant newlines.

Comment: After a loop like `for (int k = 0; k < 100; k++) { /*stuff*/ }` the variable `k` does not exist. It only existed inside the loop.

Comment: Fixed the formatting for you...

Comment: Function `gets()` is obsolete and is no longer part of the standard C library. Please read [Why is the gets function so dangerous that it should not be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used) It's also likely to cause you problems mixing a line-reading function with `scanf`. Use `scanf`, or use `fgets()` followed by `sscanf()` or other string-processing functions, butn don't mix them until you are completely familiar with their quirks.

Comment: You are using `scanf("%s", ..)` to read titles of things. This doesn't really work. Titles in general consist of more than one word.

Comment: @WeatherVane `"%s"` is is every bit as bad as `gets` but somehow we tend to let it slip. Please do not use `"%s"`! If you need to read a string, *always* include field width, for example, `"%99s"` (99 rather than 100 to allow for the null terminator).

Answer (score 1):

To understand your problem you first need to understand [scope](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scope-rules-in-c/).

In C there are 2 types of scopes: global scope and local scope. Variables in the global scope are able to be accessed anywhere in the program after where they're defined. Variables in the local scope are slightly more complex. When you create a variable in a function it is accessible anywhere inside that function after where it is defined. Also note that there are a couple of other cases where a local scope may apply that I won't go over in here.

In your case you created a variable inside a loop that can't be accessed outsize of that loop. Meaning you must create the variable inside the *function* scope not the *loop* scope. Just do what you did earlier putting the defining the variable outside the loop like you did with `n` & `l`. I.E.

```
int i;
for(i=0;i<numBooks;i++){  
    printf("Book %d\n",i+1); 
    printf("Title: "); 
    scanf("%s",&books[i].title); 
    printf("Volume: "); 
    scanf("%d",&books[i].volume); 
    printf("Year: "); 
    scanf("%d",&books[i].year); 
    printf("Author: "); 
    gets(books[i].author); 
}
```

TL;DR:
Change the [scope](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scope-rules-in-c/) of your variables like above. Also, I did if for [you](https://pastebin.com/yjNqvcdx)

Answer (score 0):

This code will not work correctly:

```
for(int i=0;i<numBooks;i++){
    //...
}
i++;
```

because the scope of `i` is the `for` loop's block. In order to be able to reuse `i` after the `for` cycle, you can declare it before the `for`:

```
int i;
for(i=0;i<numBooks;i++){
    //...
}
i++;
```

But, even thought this is syntactically correct, you may ask yourself: Do I really need this? After all, at the end of the `for` cycle it's pretty clear that `i` will end up being equal with `numBooks`.